# How to repeat, circle XHR requests, handle multiple XHR requests in Cypress

Tags: cypress

How to make through an interval requests before tests?
I tried 2 ways to retry requests but either was failing;

I need to upload a file, waiting till one got imported successfully

On the first step i upload a file to my server in cypress

```
    before( ()=> {
      //my custom POST command
      cy.form_request(url, data)
        .then(({id}) => {
```

Then i wait for id of the uploaded file

```
          check_It_Till_Success_It(id);
        })
    })
```

Then the received id i pass into a new request to verified its status on the server and need to repeat the request till the file processing is finished. 
At the solution below it says

***CypressError: cy.wait() only accepts aliases for routes.
The alias: 'check_it_request' did not match a route.***

```
  function check_It_Till_Success_It(id) {

    function checkRequest() {
      cy.request("GET", "http://localhost:28080/admin/api/catalog/import/status/" + id)
        .then(({status}) => {
          if (status === "FINISHED" || status === "FAILED") {
            clearInterval(check_It);
          } else {
            console.log('retry one more time');
          }
        }).as('check_it_request');
      cy.wait("@check_it_request");
    }

    checkRequest();

    const check_It =  setInterval(checkRequest, 1000);
  }
```

or here is another my solution through a recursive requesting:

```
  function check_It_Till_Success_It(id) {

    return (
      cy.request("GET", BASE_URL + "/admin/api/catalog/import/status/" + id)
        .then(({status}) => {
          if (status === "FINISHED" || status === "FAILED") {
            console.log('success');
          } else {
            console.log('retry one more time');
            setTimeout(() => check_It_Till_Success_It(id), 1000)
          }
        })
    )
  }
```

but it throws an error:

***Uncaught CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.***

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found my mystake because of the use of native JS tools as *setTimeout*, *setInterval*.

Cypress doesnt allow to use them and replaces with controllable methods: ***cy.clock*** and ***cy.tick***

So i took the recursion implementation and replaced with the methods above and my code became:

```
  function check_It_Till_Success_It(id) {
    cy.request("GET", BASE_URL + "/admin/api/catalog/import/status/" + id)
      .then(resp => {
        const status = resp.body.status;

        if (status === "FINISHED" || status === "FAILED") {
          console.log('success');

        } else {
          console.log('retry one more time');
          cy.clock();
          cy.tick(1000);
          check_It_Till_Success_It(id)
        }
      })
  }
```

***Offtopic note***: I'm new with Cypress and as i understood it replaces the most of the js native features so it's needed to look the docs much closer (BINGO!) or look at [issue section](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues) because some JS specific feature just crash Cypress *without any notification or catched error*, for example: FormData object crashed Cypress'es request method.